# use of unresolved identifier "Kanna", swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xpath

I want to use Kanna to parse some values of html pages. I did as they said to do it for the manual setup:

https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

I get this error message:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'Kanna'
```

And this is the code that i am using:

```
    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "your url here")!), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        for link in doc.xpath("//td/@class"){
            print(link.text!)
            //mealType.append(link.text!)
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

No need for further assistance here as i left Kanna and used Fuzi instead. Thank you.

Comment: check Library Search Paths in build settings

Comment: its empty, what should be there? @Dh1_Bh1

Comment: your project's main directory path for ex :- `ProjectName/`

Comment: also try to add this to Framework Search Paths

Comment: tried adding $(SRCROOT)/ to library and framework search paths, same error

Comment: try to reimport your library and import it like :- `import Kanna` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the import at the top of your swift file?

```
import Kanna
```

Comment: It says in the github documentation " Note: With manual installation, this library doesn't need to be imported, or namespace-qualified in your code" Even if i tried to import it, it says no such module

Comment: You're trying to use that library without cocapods or carthage?